# How to call an object of one activity in another?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to call the `databasereference` variable of `Firebase.java` activity in `showFullList.java` activity, how to do it? I have to show list retrieved from firebase in this activity with `RecyclerView`. Please help. Code is here.

**Firebase.java**

public class Firebase extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText EDname;
Button addB;
Spinner choose;

DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("School");

    EDname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etname);
    addB= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);
    choose = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerchoose);

    addB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            addData();
        }
    });
}

private void addData()
{
    String name = EDname.getText().toString().trim();
    String section = choose.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
    {

        String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
        Model model = new Model(id,name,section);
        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(model);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Artist Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }else
        {

            Toast.makeText(this,"Enter Name ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
}
```

}

**showFullList.java**

```
public class ShowFullList extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerViewList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_full_list);
        recyclerViewList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    }
}
```

how to access the firebase instance here in an `onStart()` method with `addEventValueListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can initiate `DatabaseReference` as many times you need in different activities.
2. You should not write dependent code.
3. For activities which are not ensured to keep in stack. You should create new instance of variables instead of using previous activity instances.

You can achieve `DatabaseReference` like this.

```
public class ShowFullList extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerViewList;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_full_list);
        recyclerViewList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("School");
       }
    }
```

Comment: +1. No activity should ever attempt to access another activity. You can't count on any other activity existing at all, even if it's conceptually in the backstack.

Comment: hmmm.. Thanks!!

Comment: You can mark right this answer to encourage me @Ziad